# I can't connect to postgresql database in deployment

Tags: django, postgresql, backend, pythonanywhere

Hello I just want to deploy my django project in python anywhere .... and when I run the command `python manage.py migrate`

it shows this error message `django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "<Host name>" (<IP address>), port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?`
I think that the problem in python anywhere because when I connect to the server in `pgadmin` using the same info in the `settings.py` file I don't get any error messages and you have to know that I am using `neon.tech` for my postgresql database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '<the database>',
        'USER':'<User>',
        'PASSWORD':'<Password>',
        'HOST':'<Host>',
        'PORT':5432,
    }
}
```

and I am sure that all information is right because I used it to connect to the server in pgadmin in my local machiene

Comment: If you're using a free account on PythonAnywhre, you won't be able to cennect to an external service.

Comment: Ok thank you ... and I want to ask if there any way to use external servise for free in any website .

Comment: On free account you can use allow-listed domains (mostly [public API endpoints](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/)) + GMail's [SMTP servers](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SMTPForFreeUsers/#use-gmails-smtp-servers).  Regarding databases, you can use a MySQL db on a free account.

Comment: hmm Ok I will try to user MySQL

Comment: Cool, if you have any issues write to PythonAnywhere support directly, we're happy to help.